# Excel to be grouped

Tags: excel, perl

I'm having an excel in which the first column contains Roll numbers of students like  1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc  and the second column contains their marks in subjects 30 40 60 for each semester. I want to know just get the highest marks each student scored only im my excel. I have alsmost 1000 students.
Below is the format.   Want to add that i want to do this using perl scripting languages

```
Students  Marks Obtained
1.1       45
1.1       68
1.1       69
1.2       70
1.2       14
1.2       48
.
.
.
9.9       87
9.9       76
9.9       66
9.9       100
```

Comment: use [pivot table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-HA102840046.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

this Code starting from C16:

```
Dim StartX As Integer
Dim StartY As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim TmpS As String
Dim TmpI As Integer

StartX = 16
StartY = 3
TmpS = ""
TmpI = 0
For i = StartX To 9999
    If Cells(i, StartY).Value = "" Then Exit For

    If TmpS <> Cells(i, StartY).Value Then
        If i <> StartX Then
            Cells(i - 1, StartY + 2).Value = TmpI
            TmpI = Cells(i, StartY + 1).Value
        End If
    Else
        If TmpI < Cells(i, StartY + 1).Value Then TmpI = Cells(i, StartY + 1).Value
    End If
    TmpS = Cells(i, StartY).Value
Next
Cells(i - 1, StartY + 2).Value = TmpI
```

read all the cells and write near every student the max Rate
If you prefer you can put in an array or write in another sheet...